# Admob view gets destroyed when scrolling in expandable listview

Tags: android, view, admob, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am currently using a custom ExpandableListView that displays either items of my app or some AdMob views, and these AdMob views keep getting destroyed and recreated when I scroll in my activity.

Let's take an example. If the 5th item of my expandableListView is an AdView, it gets destroyed when I scroll down the list (so this item is not visible on the screen anymore) and recreated when i scroll up again. I see that the view was destroyed in the logcat

```
12-14 17:28:43.383: D/webviewglue(23775): nativeDestroy view: 0x5149d4c8
```

I would like the Admob view not to be destroyed and recreated when I'm scrolling up and down. It makes my activity (An activity with Fragments btw) laggy and the ads popping in the ExpandableListView are quite disturbing. I wonder if it comes from my implementation of the ExpandableListAdapter or if it comes from the AdMob view itself.

Do you guys have any idea of the source of this problem?

Thanks !